# Where can I find all of the hidden socks?

Tags: pajama-sam

I'm playing "Pajama Sam 1: No Need to Hide when it's Dark Outside", and there is an optional task to find 8 socks throughout the game. I'm fairly certain that it unlocks some sort easter egg at the end of the game.

Where can I find all of the socks?

Answer (score 1):

I made a spreadsheet on this (for speedrunning purposes). The sock locations are randomized with every run, but the spreadsheet contains all the sock location I know of (56 total, or 28 unique pairs). However, the game randomly picks 10 pairs from these, so you only need to find 20 total socks in any one run. Here's the link [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1374BEhkaCQ_MNKNCtbTxKAg3fa2Bcdyil1qip-pGdVU/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: If your link dies, your answer becomes effectively useless -- that's the hallmark of a "link only" answer (can't stand alone without the link.) The answer itself should contain the relevant and necessary information, linking to an external page with more detail as needed.